# Google Form embed default value for a field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Rails app that displays a Googe Form in a Bootstrap modal.

Here is a picture of the browser:

[image]

I would like to add a default to the `name` input field.

This is the coffeescript code - that doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#gformshow2").click ->
    alert "hi"
    document.getElementById("entry_252495961").value="david"
    return
```

The "hi" alert displays just before the modal is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the form is in an iframe which you have no access to. The coffeescript code gets executed on your page, not the Google form.

As far as I know it is not possible for you to modify the content of that Google Form (think of the security implications… it would mean that you could fill it out for them, even submitting it without their consent)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.bettercloud.com/monitor/the-academy/set-pre-filled-responses-in-google-forms/

To set a pre-filled response in Google Forms:

Create a Google Form like you normally would
Click the ‘Responses’ section in the toolbar
Click ‘Get pre-filled URL’
Fill out any fields you would like pre-filled and click submit
Copy the new URL at the top of your screen and share that, rather than the conventional URL